# Apache Flink 1.14.0 - Unable to use python UDF through SQL DDL in Java

Tags: apache-flink, user-defined-functions, flink-table-api

I'm trying to execute the python UDF function in SQL DDL(1.14.0)

Python file here：

```
from pyflink.table import DataTypes
from pyflink.table.udf import udf


@udf(input_types=[DataTypes.INT()], result_type=DataTypes.INT())
def add_one(a: int):
    return a + 1
```

And start flink cluster:

```
➜  flink-1.14.0 ./bin/start-cluster.sh
Starting cluster.
Starting standalonesession daemon on host magiclian-ubuntu.
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host magiclian-ubuntu.
```

Java code here:

```
public class PyUDF {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

        //set cfg
        tEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration().setString("python.files",
                "/home/magic/workspace/python/flinkTestUdf/udfTest.py");
        tEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration().setString("python.client.executable", "python3");
        tEnv.executeSql(
                "CREATE TEMPORARY SYSTEM FUNCTION add1 AS 'udfTest.add_one' LANGUAGE PYTHON"
        );

        TableResult ret1 = tEnv.executeSql("select add1(3)");
        ret1.print();

        env.execute();
    }
}
```

And then run the job through Flink client:

```
flink run /home/magic/workspace/flink-jobs/UDF/pythonUDF/target/pythonUDF-1.0.0.jar
```

Error is :

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: SQL validation failed. Cannot instantiate user-defined function 'add1'.
```

**But when i use sql-client to execute my py UDF, it runs successfully.**

Start sql-client:

```
PYFLINK_CLIENT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3  ./sql-client.sh embedded -pyexec /usr/bin/python3 -pyfs home/magic/workspace/python/flinkTestUdf/udfTest.py
```

Then

`create temporary system function add1 as 'udfTest.add_one' language python;`

Then

`select add1(3);`

I got the correct result `4` and is there something wrong with my code?

I see that the py UDF function was supported in version `1.11` `https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-106%3A+Support+Python+UDF+in+SQL+Function+DDL`, but now i'm using 1.14.0.

Who can help me out!

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Is there any update, could you solve the problem?.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the dependencies all installed.

Java :

- 8 or 11
- maven 3.5+
- flink jars:

  ```
    <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
               <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
               <version>${flink.version}</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
               <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
               <version>${flink.version}</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
               <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
               <version>${flink.version}</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
               <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge_2.11</artifactId>
               <version>${flink.version}</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
               <artifactId>flink-table-common</artifactId>
               <version>${flink.version}</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
               <artifactId>flink-table-planner_2.11</artifactId>
               <version>${flink.version}</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
               <artifactId>flink-python_2.11</artifactId>
               <version>${flink.version}</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
  ```

Python :

- Python 3.6+
- Apache Beam（== 2.19.0）
- pip（>= 7.1.0）
- setupTools（>= 37.0.0）
- apache-fink (1.14.0)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Pyflink version and Flink version in Java match. For the new commers, the current pom.xml should be

```
<properties>
        (...)
    <flink.version>1.15.1</flink.version>
</properties>
```

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
    <!-- These dependencies are provided, because they should not be packaged into the JAR file. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-clients -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add connector dependencies here. They must be in the default scope (compile). -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add logging framework, to produce console output when running in the IDE. -->
    <!-- These dependencies are excluded from the application JAR by default. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.py4j/py4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.py4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>py4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.9.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-table -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-table-api-java-bridge -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-table-planner -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table-planner_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- added as chunk -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table-common</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-table -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-python -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-python_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- added as chunk -->
</dependencies>
```